# Gson Type Adapter with both custom and default deserialization logic

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have a gson model class which contains a variable named `duration` which is an integer. The problem is that when this variable has no value the server instead of returning me `null` it returns `""`.

This is also the case with lists, when I am expecting a `List<String>?` and there is no value in them I get `""` instead of `null`. Unfortunately the server can not change.

I have fixed the problem with a custom `double` deserializer but I need something more generic because the "" is the default server approach. Here is my progress so far but on the else branch I do not know how to tell it to continue with the default deserializer.

```
internal class BadDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Any> {

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(
            json: JsonElement,
            type: Type,
            context: JsonDeserializationContext): Any? {
        return try {
            val json = json.asString
            if (json.isBlank()) {
                null
            } else {
               //Do nothing and call default behavior (?)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw JsonParseException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an unfortunate response getting an empty string.

AFAIK you can't register a type adapter for primitive types with GSON, though perhaps its possible to register one for their boxed types (not sure how this may work with Kotlin).

If you can use the boxed types, then you could use something like the following:

```java
public class DoubleAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(final JsonElement json,
                              final Type typeOfT,
                              final JsonDeserializationContext ctx) throws JsonParseException {
        if (!json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            throw new JsonParseException("primitive expected");
        }
        final JsonPrimitive primitive = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();

        if (primitive.isString()) {
            final String value = primitive.getAsString();
            if ("".equals(value)) return null;
            throw new JsonParseException("double expected, not string");
        }

        if (!primitive.isNumber()) {
            throw new JsonParseException("double expected");
        }
        return primitive.getAsNumber().doubleValue();
    }

}
```

Though it might be cleaner (and I usually do for everything) to write an adapter for whatever structure you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your approach is good but it works only for doubles which as I stated have fixed. That's why I need a more broad approach which would take in mind Double, Int, List etc

Comment: Oh I see, misintrepreted the question somewhat. I'll give it some thought, but its possible you could achieve this by using a TypeAdapterFactory - I'm just trying to wrap my head arround how you could approach this.